# Using case_when followed by a select statement in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a case_when in dplyr followed by a select statement and getting an error.  I am either not doing this correctly or maybe a bug?

```
mtc2 <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(Model = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
  mutate(UserComment = case_when(
                       grepl("Mazda", Model) ~ "Very Fun",
                       grepl("Cadillac", Model) ~ "Favorite",
                       TRUE ~ "Other")) %>% 
select(Model, UserComment, everything())
```

When I separate the "select" from the block it works fine.

```
mtc3 <- mtcars %>% 
   mutate(Model = row.names(mtcars)) %>% 
   mutate(UserComment = case_when(
                        grepl("Mazda", Model) ~ "Very Fun",
                        grepl("Cadillac", Model) ~ "Favorite",
                        TRUE ~ "Other"))

mtc3 <- mtc3 %>% 
   select(Model, UserComment, everything())
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
> grepl("Mazda", Model) ~ "Very Fun",
Error: unexpected ',' in "grepl("Mazda", Model) ~ "Very Fun","
>     grepl("Cadillac", Model) ~ "Favorite",
Error: unexpected ',' in "    grepl("Cadillac", Model) ~ "Favorite","
>     TRUE ~ "Other")) %>% 
Error: unexpected ')' in "    TRUE ~ "Other")"
>   select(Model, UserComment, everything())
Error in select(Model, UserComment, everything()) : 
  object 'Model' not found

> grepl("Mazda", Model) ~ "Very Fun",
Error: unexpected ',' in "grepl("Mazda", Model) ~ "Very Fun","
>     grepl("Cadillac", Model) ~ "Favorite",
Error: unexpected ',' in "    grepl("Cadillac", Model) ~ "Favorite","
>     TRUE ~ "Other")) %>% 
Error: unexpected ')' in "    TRUE ~ "Other")"
>   select(Model, UserComment, everything())
Error in select(Model, UserComment, everything()) : 
 object 'Model' not found
```

dplyr version 0.7.3 and R version 3.3.3.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, what's your dplyr version? what's your error?

Comment: Sorry for not including the error.  I edited to include that.

Comment: OK, so I exited RStudio and relaunched and now it works fine.  No error.